# FastMarching method from MATLAB alternative in OpenCV C++

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv

I am currently working on image processing software from MATLAB code to C++ with OpenCV.
I came upon the imseggmm function in MATLAB ([Link](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imsegfmm.html)) which use the internal MEX fastMarchingMex which return a distance map.

There seems to be no equivalent at this day in OpenCV, and implementations using OpenCV are not very common (in fact, nonexistent on the web)

My question is: do other functions that do the same exact job exists even with Superior computation time? (computation time is not an issue in my case)

EDIT: as pointed by comment, my question is not very clear.
Let's say that for me, performance is not important, I only search a function that output the same exact results as the FastMarching method.

I tested the DistanceTransform function which did not returned the same results at all with my test sample.
There seems to be something I don't understand in the process of the FastMarching method, that differ from others distance calculation methods.

My MATLAB code use fastMarching providing it a binary image of zeros and ones, and an index of those non-zero points (in linear array coordinates). It return a distance map.

Please consider also this is the first time I post a question on StackOverflow, I hope I have not been annoying and that my question, if it got an answer, will help other people to find an alternative to this function.

Comment: [watershed](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/d1b/group__imgproc__misc.html#ga3267243e4d3f95165d55a618c65ac6e1)

Comment: There is only 1 actual question in this "question", and it asks if functions exist with better performance. Then you state performance is **not** an issue for you, which makes it confusing what you're actually asking? Welcome to Stack Overflow, please take the [tour] and read [ask], because currently this question is off topic for being broad, asking for recommendations, and potentially being unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Hi Wolfie, thanks for your answer. Sorry for my question being not very clear.
In fact, my question is more : "does other algorithms than FastMarching method exists that produces the same exact result ?"

Comment: In which case this extract from the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) expands on my final point: *"4.Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. "*. Instead of asking for broad recommendations, show a small example of what you have working in MATLAB, with reproducible inputs/outputs and a description of what the function *does*. Then it's a more on-topic performance question.

Comment: Fast marching is one way to implement the weighted distance transform. I don't think OpenCV has such a function. [DIPlib does](https://diplib.org/diplib-docs/distance.html#dip-GreyWeightedDistanceTransform-dip-Image-CL-dip-Image-CL-dip-Image-CL-dip-Image-L-dip-Metric--dip-String-CL) (disclaimer: I am one of the authors of DIPlib).